# how can i filter items in some dictionaries?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

My view:

```
new = Product.objects.all().order_by('-time_add')[:10]
discount = Product.objects.all().order_by('-discount')[:10]
papular = Product.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('liked')).order_by('-num_likes')[:10]
free_shipping = Product.objects.filter(free_shipping=True).order_by('-time_add')[:10]

items = {'new':new, 'discount':discount, 'papular':papular, 'free_shipping':free_shipping}

return render(request, 'index.html', {'items':items})
```

I want to filter and show products in the above categories. But each Item may be in multiple categories. What should I do to mark products and avoid duplicate items when showing all of them in the template? Should I change my queries in views.py or change template tags? I test queries. they retrieve correct data.

The output should be something like this:
new: a, b, c, d, e
discount: b, d, f, i
papular: a, c, g
free_shipping: d, f, h

and all items without duplicates:
all: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i

I have not any problem in HTML, CSS or js. The problem is just to mark products that are in two categories with python/tags in view/template.
It's my template:

```
<div class="featured__controls">
    <ul>
        <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
        <li data-filter=".popular">Popular</li>
        <li data-filter=".new">New</li>
        <li data-filter=".discount">Discount</li>
        <li data-filter=".free_shipping">Free Shipping</li>
    </ul>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="row featured__filter">
    {% for key, value in items.items %}
        <div class="all {{key}}">
            {% for i in vlaue %}
                <div class="featured__item">
                    <div class="featured__item__text">
                        <h6><a href="#">{{i.name}}</a></h6>
                        <h5>{{i.price}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I removed additional lines. I gave each item a label ({{key}} value), but just one label. Finally, I have duplicate items with different labels instead of one item with several labels.

Thank you all

Comment: items should not be repeated . on what basis can we decide where the item is shown if duplicated? in which key

Comment: @MohitHarshan Sorry, I didn't understand. I retrieved some items and grouped them in 4 cats. each item has a label depend on its cat. but some items are in multiple cats. how can I give them two or more label? I don't want to show duplicated items.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be , You can take all Product and annotate the tags

```
 from django.db.models import Case, When, Value
    

   Product.objects.all().annotate(
     new = Case(When(id__in=new.values_list("id", flat=True),then=Value(True)),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        )
     discount = Case(When(id__in=discount.values_list("id", flat=True), then=Value(True)),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        ),
     papular = Case(When(id__in=papular.values_list("id", flat=True), then=Value(True)),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        ),
     free_shipping = Case(When(id__in=free_shipping.values_list("id", flat=True),then=Value(True)),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        ),

   )

new_products = Product.objects.filter(new=True) 
discount_products = Product.objects.filter(discount=True).exclude(id__in=new_products)
free_shipping_products = Product.objects.filter(free_shipping=True).exclude(id__in=discount_products)
popular_products = Product.objects.filter(papular=True).exclude(id__in=free_shipping_products)
```

Pass this new dictionary as context

```
  {'new':new_products, 'discount':discount_products, 'popular':popular_products,'free_shipping':free_shipping_products}
```

Now in templates you can loop through the each, and add tags like:

```
      {% if product.new %}
        New
      {% endif %}
      {% if product.discount %}
        Discount
      {% endif %}
```